# Sublime Text Multiple Files Hint

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text as My Editor, Sublime Text Doesn't allow auto-complete or code hints between multiple files, instead you get hints for functions or variables that are located in the same file your working on. How can i get code hints of a function that is located in another file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is what you are looking for I guess: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/All%20Autocomplete

Comment: Thanks, Indeed it's what i'm looking for.